# First checkbox should be checked in ng-repeat if button clicked

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi all I am new to angularjs could anybody help me please? All what I need when I click a button the first checkbox in ng-repeat list to be checked. Am I doing anything wrong? Here is my code:

### Checkbox

```
<fieldset class="top5">
    <legend title="Categories"><span class="info blackLabelUpper"><b>Dish Categories</b><span class="TextCtrlReqBgImage">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></span></legend>
    <span class="checkbox-list" ng-repeat="dishType in dishTypes">
        <input type='checkbox'  ng-click="toggleDishType(dishType)" ng-model="dishType.checked" value="{{dishType}}" ng-checked="selectedDish.Type.indexOf(dishType) > -1">
        {{dishType}}<br />
    </span>
</fieldset>
```

### Button

```
<kendo-button id="btnNewDish" class="k-primary" ng-click="onNewDishClick(true)">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i>New Dish
</kendo-button>
```

### Function

```
scope.onNewDishClick = function (showNewDIshMessage) {
    scope.dishTypes[0].dishType = true;
}
```

Comment: try this `<input type='checkbox'  ng-click="toggleDishType(dishType)" ng-model="dishType.checked" value="{{dishType.checked}}" />`

Comment: Thanks Ramesh I need the first checkbox in the list to be checked when the button clicked. I have another roles where I needed to be unchecked.

Comment: `<input type='checkbox' ng-click="toggleDishType(dishType)" ng-model="dishType.dishType " value="{{dishType.dishType }}"` because you are saving in `dishType` property in function

Comment: Thanks Karan I tried this but I didn't work. The action should just happened if I click the button. I dont wont to default the checkbox to be checked.

Comment: Instead of ng-model="dishType.checked" try this ng-model="dishType".

Comment: Thanks Nikita I tried also but it didn't work. Do we realy need ng-model?

Answer (score 0):

I think the **Function** definition should be like this :

```
scope.onNewDishClick = function (showNewDIshMessage) {
 scope.dishTypes[0].checked = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="restorent_type in restaurant_types" style="margin:5px;" class="col col-offset-10">
    <label class="item item-radio radio-label {{restorent_type.RESCOD}}">
        <input type="checkbox" name="group" ng-model="restorent.types" value="{{restorent_type.RESCOD}}" ng-click="filters.RESCOD = restorent_type.RESCOD" ng-checked="$first">       
        <div class="item-content">
            {{restorent_type.RESCOD}}
        </div>
        <i class="radio-icon ion-checkmark"></i>
    </label>
</div>
```

Or you can use the :

```
ng-model="dishType.checked" ng-init="dishType.checked=true"
```

Comment: Thanks Kunvar the peoblem with ng-checked="$first" it will default the first checkbox to be checked which is not correct the checkbox should be checked just when the event has been clicked.

Comment: its ok,

But we can show the first check box by default selected.

Comment: Yes but the logic should be when the event has been clicked. I have another logic where the user don't wont any checkbox to be selected

Answer (score 0):

When you use `ng-model` on your inputs you don't need to use `value` to get result because `ng-model` save changes on self.

Feel free to ask question, and this sample maybe helps you.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  $scope.items = [
    {somthing: false, title: 'a'},
    {somthing: false, title: 'b'},
    {somthing: false, title: 'c'},
    {somthing: false, title: 'd'},
    {somthing: false, title: 'e'}
  ]
  
  
  $scope.checkAll = function(){
    angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item){
      item.somthing = !item.somthing;
    });
  }
  
  $scope.checkFirstItem = function(){
      $scope.items[0].somthing = !$scope.items[0].somthing;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
      
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.somthing">
      {{item.somthing}}
      {{item.title}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  
  <button ng-click="checkAll()">check all</button>
  <button ng-click="checkFirstItem()">check first item</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this but for some reason it didn't work. The problem I am trying to develop code which has Telerik and angularjs and I have no background in one of them ;-)